# How to split string into Int:String Dictionary

Tags: swift, split

So I'm trying to split a string that would look like this:

```
let Ingredients = "1:egg,4:cheese,2:flour,50:sugar"
```

and I'm attempting to get a dictionary output like this

```
var decipheredIngredients : [Int:String] = [

1 : "egg",
4 : "cheese",
2 : "flour",
50 : "sugar"

]
```

Here is the code that I am attempting this with

```
func decipherIngredients(input: String) -> [String:Int]{
    let splitStringArray = input.split(separator: ",")
    var decipheredIngredients : [String:Int] = [:]
    for _ in splitStringArray {
        decipheredIngredients.append(splitStringArray.split(separator: ":"))
    }

    return decipheredIngredients
}
```

When I try this I get an error saying I can't append to the dictionary.  I've tried other methods like this:

```
func decipherIngredients(input: String) -> [String.SubSequence]{
    let splitStringArray = input.split(separator: ",")
    return splitStringArray
}

let newThing = decipherIngredients(input: "1:egg,4:cheese,2:flour,50:sugar").split(separator: ":")
print(newThing)
```

but I get this as the output of the function

```
[ArraySlice(["1:egg", "4:cheese", "2:flour", "50:sugar"])]
```

Comment: Are they really keys? Or just the amount of their ingredients ? If they are the amount you should use an array of tuples. If the amount has no meaning I think you should just discard them and create a plain array with the ingredients.

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I should have looked more into what dictionaries really are because I thought that it was just a way of linking two data types into one array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative approach using **Swift 4** and functional programming:

```
let ingredients = "1:egg,4:cheese,2:flour,50:sugar"

let decipheredIngredients = ingredients.split(separator: ",").reduce(into: [Int: String]()) {
  let ingredient = $1.split(separator: ":")

  if let first = ingredient.first, let key = Int(first), let value = ingredient.last {
    $0[key] = String(value)
  }
}

print(decipheredIngredients)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

try this, assuming you want dictionary keys of type Int and values of type String

```
func decipherIngredients(_ input: String) -> [Int:String] {

    var decipheredIngredients : [Int:String] = [:]

    let keyValueArray = input.components(separatedBy: ",")

    for keyValue in keyValueArray {
        let components = keyValue.components(separatedBy: ":")
        decipheredIngredients[Int(components[0])!] = components[1]
    }

    return decipheredIngredients

}
```